# How to divide a mesh in 20

Tags: mesh, faces

I have a rectangle that i want to divide in 20 faces verticaly

like this:

[image]

How can i do it? i need it to be exactly 20 faces

Answer (score 2):

- Plane ..(single quad face, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>dissolve internal edges if not)
- Edge Mode, select long edges, right-click menu > 'Subdivide'
- In the adjust last operator panel, (bottom left of 3D view) set the number of cuts to 19.

Comment: I dont have the option to set the number of cuts on operator panel

Comment: @LeonelAmaral do you have the panel? If so, it's the top item..

Comment: I found it, I need to press ctrl+r do see it, thank you

Comment: @LeonelAmaral.. yup,  Ctrl - R is another way, cutting loops into a 1-face face ring... it's a different operation, if you have more than one face.